# Why did none of my German players get called up for the World Cup?

Tags: football-manager-2013

I'm playing Bayern München, so I have 90% of the best German players, and 90% of their national team. However, the 2014 World Cup just came and went, and none of my Germans got called up, although my players from other countries did.

All my players had a great season and I won the league. I checked international instructions (under "int friendly availability") and none of my German players are showing up there. What gives? Are they all retired or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that RobP gave is correct. Sports Interactive do not have the legal rights to have real players play for these teams, not only German.

http://www.footballmanagerwiki.co.uk/index.php?title=Fake_National_Teams_and_Players

You can fix this by going into program files & deleting the fake.lnc and nleague.lnc files in your 'db' folder.
You can find those files in:

If you're using Steam: C:\Program Files\Steam\Steamapps\Common\Football Manager X\data\db*whatever database you want to use*\lnc

If not using Steam: C:\Program Files\Sports Interactive\Football Manager X\data\db*whatever database you want to use*\lnc

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as it contains information on how to circumvent this issue. It would be helpful if you added it to your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

FM2013, like with some of the previous versions, doesn't have a license to allow real names of German national players. So it has to put a block on those players being called up to the World Cup. There are ways around it however.

Comment: If you know that there are ways around this limitation, then I think it would be beneficial to the asker to describe those ways.

Comment: Or if there's a source for this information.  That, especially, would help your case.